# How to store multiple items on Local Storage when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store multiple items based on this function:

```
onclick="s(iId)"
```

This is the function that I'm using:

```
function s(i_id) {
    var items = [];
    items.push(i_id);
    localStorage.setItem("i", JSON.stringify(i));
}
```

The problem is that it is only storing one id when the button is clicked and refreshed every time is clicked. How can I make it store multiple ids?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, you're creating a new array, pushing a single id in it, and then saving it every time the function is called. Two things you could do is move the `items` array outside of the function, and simply push to it, before saving them. The second option is, getting the already stored value, parsing it with `JSON.parse` and pushing a new item in it, before saving it again.

I suggest going with option 1, even if it creates a global variable. It's much faster.

```
var items = [];

function store(item_id) {
    items.push(item_id);
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Comment: It still does not store new values. It just store one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the onclick like this:

```
onclick="store([itemId1, itemId2, itemId3])"
```

and the function:

```
function store(item_ids) {
    var items = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < item_ids.length; i++) {
        items.push(item_ids[i]);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Considering if you want to add new array to storage on every click...